# How to get dynamic component presentation on DD4T2 (.NET)?

Tags: dd4t, broker, dd4t-2

I've published a component and verified that it's in the broker database:

[image: Screenshot of Broker DB's CP table]

I'd like to retrieve this dynamic component presentation on the web app using DD4T.

My current attempt:

```
private DynamicContentViewModel GetDynamicComponentPresentation()
{
    var publicationResolver = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPublicationResolver>();
    var publicationId = publicationResolver.ResolvePublicationId();
    const string schemaId = "tcm:3-907-8";

    var queryParameters = new ExtendedQueryParameters
    {
        PublicationId = publicationId,
        QuerySchemas = new[] { schemaId }
    };

    var componentPresentationFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IComponentPresentationFactory>();
    var componentPresentations = componentPresentationFactory.FindComponentPresentations(queryParameters);
    var dynamicContent = new List<DynamicContentViewModel>();
    var viewModelFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IViewModelFactory>();

    foreach (var componentPresentation in componentPresentations)
    {
        var model = viewModelFactory.BuildViewModel<DynamicContentViewModel>(componentPresentation);
        dynamicContent.Add(model);
    }

    return dynamicContent.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This is returning an 0 component presentation. I've attempted to use the schema ID of DynamicComponent.

Another approach:

```
private DynamicComponent GetDynamicComponentPresentation()
{
    var componentPresentationFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IComponentPresentationFactory>();
    var componentUri = "tcm:18-916-32";
    var componentPresentation = componentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentation(componentUri);
    var viewModelFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IViewModelFactory>();
    var model = viewModelFactory.BuildViewModel<DynamicComponent>(componentPresentation);
    return model;
}
```

In the second approach, it's throwing an error. After having a look at "DD4T.Factories.ComponentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentation(String componentUri, StringtemplateUri)", I found that it's throwing a `ComponentPresentationNotFoundException`. Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: The component ID in the code is 916, while the database screenshot shows 917. That couldn't by any chance explain why the second code snippet doesn't work, could it?

Comment: That's embarrassing. I'm getting a different error regarding an exception during a web client request but I'll investigate that first.

Comment: Component type ID should be 16 not 32, not required to pass var componentUri = "tcm:18-916"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcm ID we're incorrect.

```
private DynamicComponent GetDynamicComponentPresentation()
{
    var componentPresentationFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IComponentPresentationFactory>();
    var componentUri = "tcm:18-917-16";
    var componentPresentation = componentPresentationFactory.GetComponentPresentation(componentUri);
    var viewModelFactory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IViewModelFactory>();
    var model = viewModelFactory.BuildViewModel<DynamicComponent>(componentPresentation);
    return model;
}
```